# Blank retrieve password page after 2.5.5 > 2.7.2 update

Tags: password

When i click on the link to reset the password, I get a blank page. How can I debug this?

The reset link is something like that:  http://mysite.com/?ACT=14&id=Rr2Z8OrG

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forgot password process was [**changed in EE 2.6**](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/new-forgotten-password-tool-for-expressionengine-26).

> With ExpressionEngine 2.6 comes a much-improved experience for
>   resetting a forgotten password. Users will be sent a single email with
>   a link to a new password form. This lets the user decide what their
>   new password will be, rather than having the system send a new,
>   plain-text password in a second email. After filling in a new password, users will be able to login straight
>   away and get right back to work!

EE uses the standard [**Member Profile**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/themes/member_profile_templates.html) and the [**Messages**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/message_pages/index.html) templates for this flow and the password reset link is valid for 24 hours.

I can't tell you where in the process your setup is broken but sounds like the user isn't getting to the correctly place for the new password reset process. I'd start by checking to make sure you have member templates loaded to the server.

Comment: I was using a plugin, so password retrieve process was a bit different. Unluckily even the new process won't work, but this will be a new request. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this on the front end or the backend? The front end system changed the forgot password functionality recently to use a password reset form on the front end that relies on the member templates (yuck). The idea was that instead of sending a random general password a user could reset their password with a form after validating an email link.

Answer (score 0):

The reset link from the CP should be something like:

> http://www.site.com/system/index.php?S=0&D=cp&C=login&M=forgotten_password_form

Sounds like the upgrade process didn't complete 100%. I would try uploading the 2.7.2 files again and run the upgrade process again.